# Not able to perform multiple sed operations at a time

Tags: sed, ksh

Hi i need to perform multiple sed operations at a time and then flush the output to a file. 
I have a .dat file which has data as follows

**indicator.dat**

Air_Ind - A.Air_Ind Air_Ind - 0000 - 00- 00
Rpting_Ind - Case When Dstbr_Id Is Null Then 'N' Else 'Y' End Rpting_Ind - 0000 - 00 - 00
Latitude,Longitude - A.Store_Latitude Latitude,A.Store_Longitude Longitude - 0000- 00- 00
coalesce(Pm_Cig_Direct_Ind,'') - Coalesce(Direct_Acct_Ind ,'') - 0004 - 01- 01
coalesce(Pm_Mst_Direct_Ind,'') - Coalesce(Direct_Acct_Ind ,'') - 0004 - 02 - 02
coalesce(Pm_Snus_Direct_Ind,'') - Coalesce(Direct_Acct_Ind ,'') - 0004 - 01 - 02
coalesce(Pm_Snuf_Direct_Ind,'') - Coalesce(Direct_Acct_Ind ,'') - 0004 - 04- 02
coalesce(Jmc_Cgr_Direct_Ind,'') - Coalesce(Direct_Acct_Ind ,'') - 2000 - 02 - 01
coalesce(Usst_Mst_Direct_Ind,'') - Coalesce(Direct_Acct_Ind ,'') - 1070- 02- 02
coalesce(Usst_Snus_Direct_Ind,'') - Coalesce(Direct_Acct_Ind ,'') - 1070 - 01 - 02
coalesce(Usst_Snuf_Direct_Ind,'') - Coalesce(Direct_Acct_Ind ,'') - 1070 - 04 - 02

Now I am trying to replace the parameters defined in a file called `indicator.sql` and flush the output to a file

**indicator_s.sql:**

```
    Select A.Location_Id,

 param1

From Edw.Location A

--1Left Outer  Join

--1(

--1 Select

--1 Location_Id,

--1 Direct_Acct_Ind

--1 From Edw.Location_Bcbc D

--1 Where Company_Cd = 'param2'

--1 And Prod_Type_Cd = 'param3'

--1 And Prod_Catg_Cd = 'param4'

--1 ) A

--1 On L.Location_Id = A.Location_Id

Inner Join  

Mim.Mdm_Xref_Distributor D

On D.Src_Dstbr_Id=A.Location_Id

Where Sdw_Exclude_Ind='N' And Dstrb_Cd='Us'
```

the else block is not entered at any point of time

```
#!/bin/sh
rm ./Source_tmp.sql
touch ./Source_tmp.sql
while read line
do
MIM=`echo $line | cut -d " " -f1 `
EDW=`echo $line | cut -d "-" -f2 `
Company_Cd=`echo $line | cut -d "-" -f3 `
Prod_Type_Cd=`echo $line | cut -d "-" -f4 `
Prod_Catg_Cd=`echo $line | cut -d "-" -f5 `
echo "Select top 10 * from (" >> ./Source_tmp.sql ;
sed "s/Param1/$MIM/g" indicator.sql >> Source_tmp.sql;

echo "minus">> Source_tmp.sql;



if [ "$MIM"="Air_Ind " ] || [ "$MIM"="Rpting_Ind " ] || [ "$MIM"="Latitude,Longitude " ]

then


sed "s/param1/$EDW/g" indicator_s.sql >> Source_tmp.sql

else



sed -e "s/--1/' '/g" -e  "s/param1/$EDW/g" -e "s/param2/$Company_Cd/g" -e "s/param3/$Prod_Type_Cd/g" -e "s/param4/$Prod_Catg_Cd/g"  ./indicator_s.sql >> ./Source_tmp.sql



fi

done <indicator.dat
```

the output should be like the param1 and param2 etc values which i defined should be replaced from the indicator .dat file and the commented lines need to be un-commented in the else block
kindly help me

Comment: I read: _"I dont know why the sed is not working in th else block of the **ksh**"_ but in your script the shebang is `#!/bin/sh`. Please fix your question/example/tags in order to clarify if you want a `bash`, `sh` or `ksh` answer.

Comment: A UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools. The standard UNIX tool to manipulate the contents of text files is awk. You should write an awk script that does everything and just call it from whatever shell you like. The result will be more concise and robust than anything you could cook up with a mixture of shell, sed, cut, and other commands. Just clearly post samples of 1) indicator.dat, 2) indicator.sql and 3) the expected tool output and we can help you. I guarantee you'll be much happier with the result of that than what you are trying to do currently.

Comment: Are there really blank lines between every data line in `indicator.sql`?

Comment: no Ed there are no blank lines in between .

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, the `sed` command "is working". But it does not produce the expected output. I guess. To give some output example:

```
[...]
' ' Where Company_Cd = ' 0000 '

' ' And Prod_Type_Cd = ' 00 '

' ' And Prod_Catg_Cd = ' 00'
[...]
```

Obviously you have extra quotes on start of line, and extra spaced around your values.

Will this fix your issue:

```
#!/bin/bash

[...]

MIM=`echo -n $line | cut -d " " -f1 `
EDW=`echo -n $line | cut -d "-" -f2 `
Company_Cd=`echo -n $line | cut -d "-" -f3 `
Prod_Type_Cd=`echo -n $line | cut -d "-" -f4 `
Prod_Catg_Cd=`echo -n $line | cut -d "-" -f5 `

# Trim spaces as you "cut" on "-", keeping extra spaces arround
shopt -s extglob
EDW=${EDW%%+([[:space:]])}; EDW=${EDW##+([[:space:]])};
Company_Cd=${Company_Cd%%+([[:space:]])}; Company_Cd=${Company_Cd##+([[:space:]])};
Prod_Type_Cd=${Prod_Type_Cd%%+([[:space:]])}; Prod_Type_Cd=${Prod_Type_Cd##+([[:space:]])};
Prod_Catg_Cd=${Prod_Catg_Cd%%+([[:space:]])}; Prod_Catg_Cd=${Prod_Catg_Cd##+([[:space:]])};

[...]

# Fix "sed" in your "else" clause by removing extra single quotes
sed -e "s/--1/ /g" -e  "s/param1/$EDW/g" -e "s/param2/$Company_Cd/g" -e "s/param3/$Prod_Type_Cd/g" -e "s/param4/$Prod_Catg_Cd/g"  ./indicator_s.sql >> ./Source_tmp.sql
```

Producing now the much more valid SQL:

```
  [...]
  Where Company_Cd = '0000'

  And Prod_Type_Cd = '00'

  And Prod_Catg_Cd = '00'
  [...]
```

---

That being said, this is mostly some *hacks* to fix (some of ?) the various issues you might have in your script. But the whole things seems a little bit contrived. And *fragile*. As for example, it will break if any replace string contains a `&`. Here Be Dragons.

Comment: it's not at all getting replaced . that is the problem . even if extra spaces come that's fine

Comment: is there any issue with if block as the sed is working if i comment out if block and else or else it is not coming out of if block . like am i kind of missing any logical flaw which is fixing it to if block

Answer (score 0):

Its impossible to tell what you want the script to do given so far you've only posted a script that DOESN'T produce whatever output you want and you haven't posted the output you DO want, but let's start with this and you can update your question to show expected output and clarify your requirements:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN{ FS="-" }
NR==FNR { template = (template ? template ORS : "") $0; next }
{
    split($0,arr,/ /)
    MIM = arr[1]
    EDW = $1
    Company_Cd = $3
    Prod_Type_Cd = $4
    Prod_Catg_Cd = $5

    $0 = "Select top 10 * from (\n" template

    gsub(/Param1/,MIM "\nminus")
    gsub(/param1/,EDW)

    if ( MIM !~ /^Air_Ind|Rpting_Ind|Latitude,Longitude/ ) {
        gsub(/--1/," ")
        gsub(/param2/,Company_Cd)
        gsub(/param3/,Prod_Type_Cd)
        gsub(/param4/,Prod_Catg_Cd)
    }

    print
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk indicator.sql indicator.dat
Select top 10 * from (
Select A.Id,

 Air_Ind
minus

From Location A

--1Left Outer  Join

--1(

--1 Select

--1 Location_Id,

--1 Direct_Acct_Ind

--1 From Location_Bcbc D

--1 Where Company_Cd = 'param2'

--1 And Prod_Type_Cd = 'param3'

--1 And Prod_Catg_Cd = 'param4'

--1 ) A
Select top 10 * from (
Select A.Id,

 Rpting_Ind
minus

From Location A

--1Left Outer  Join

--1(

--1 Select

--1 Location_Id,

--1 Direct_Acct_Ind

--1 From Location_Bcbc D

--1 Where Company_Cd = 'param2'

--1 And Prod_Type_Cd = 'param3'

--1 And Prod_Catg_Cd = 'param4'

--1 ) A
```